# Why does a string literal beside an array like this not throw a syntax error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax

During my coding I made a mistake by calling a function like this

`someFunction( 'abc' [someValue] )`

I had forgotten the colon inside the function call.
After I found the error I played around.
An assignment like this does not throw an error as well.
`let a = 'abc'[someValue];`

I would expect a syntax error here. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: `[]` is bracket notation and can be used to access indexes or other properties (ie: .length, .includes(), etc...). So something like this would run fine: `"abc"["includes"]("b")` (gives true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string in Javascript can behave as an object and, as such has properties such as `.length` and methods such as `.slice`.  So, for any property access on an object in Javascript, one can use either the dot notation as in:

```
str.length
```

or the `[]` syntax as in:

```
str["length"]
```

or using a variable:

```
let len = "length";
str[len]
```

So, what you have with:

```
'abc' [someValue]
```

Is just that syntax.  A string followed by a property access.  That is legal Javascript.  It attempts to get the property from that object with the name of whatever string is in the `someValue` variable.

---

Here's are a couple working examples:

```js
// simple property access
let prop = "length";
console.log("abc"[prop]);

// method call
console.log("one fine day"["slice"](4, 8));
```

One would not generally code this way with a string, but it's perfectly legal as it's just part of how one can access properties on an object in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's not a syntax error. The engine thought you were trying to get a letter from that string, so if `someValue` was a number it will work perfectly fine

```js
let a = "abc"[0] 
console.log(a, "abc"[1]) //a, b
```